# WPF Frame Content Producing Audible Click (And I Don't Want the Click)

Tags: .net, wpf, frame

C# WPF .NET 4.0.

When assigning the frame content, an audible click is produced (like an unhandled event click). I don't want the audible click.

To be clear `new Page1()` does not produce the audible click.  The Frame1.content line produces the click, but the click is only created going from Page1 to a new Page1 or from a Page1 to null.  Null to null does NOT create a click.  And null to new Page1() does not produce a click.  Any ideas?

```
Page1 nextPage = new Page1("ctor string");
Frame1.content = nextPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer from the wpf team. https://connect.microsoft.com:443/VisualStudio/feedback/details/345528/webbrowser-control-in-wpf-disable-sound

Comment: Link is now dead. This is why answers should be more than just a hyperlink.