# Window emitting a sound when I try to restore it from the taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, window, minimize

I'm working on a rather big project with my team and after a while, we struck into a big problem.

Infact when we minimize the main window of the application, clicking on the taskbar to restore it results in a "bing" sound (the one that windows uses when you are trying to interact with a background window when a modal dialog is opened on it). I can't restore the window except if I press ENTER button (after obviusly clicking on it).

We are using XNA to render something inside a WindowsFormsHost component in our WPF application and the problem comes out when we change something that is not connected directly with wpf (something inside the rendering engine, so it works only with XNA).

**I can't post any code** because I don't own any rights of it and would be meaningless because the project is enough big.

**So my question is**: what are the things that can produce a problem like this one (unable to restore window sound) when you click on the taskbar?
At least I can understand where to search for this bug, because I don't even understand where I shall dirt my hands in.

**Important notes**: I'm using a splash screen and the problems come up when I do something on a second window (so not directly the main one) which is **not modal**

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Is it possible to somehow reproduce this situation in a test project using code that's not licensed by your company or something?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same but give it a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643462/wpf-frame-content-producing-audible-click-and-i-dont-want-the-click

Comment: @BoltClock: Mhh it's quite hard because what produce the problem is based upon so many objects that it's even hard to track. I don't even know where to put a breakpoint because it seems to happen BEFORE state change (when restoring), so I can break in code. BalamBalam: no sorry, that doesn't fit my question. I don't even know if it's resolvable but I tried to open a question. Does xna can interfer in some way with wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by finding out that there is a bug with an external component that we used inside our application. Still I don't understand how this bug has been created, if someone has a better answer I'll mark it.